# Extract specific file extension files with DotNetZip's ExtractSelectedEntries "Illegal characters in path."

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm trying to extract files from within a zip file using DotNetZip.

When I use the wildcard character I get an error "System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'" on `ExtractSelectedEntries`

The zip file contains a single text file, no illegal characters so I think the error is relating to the asterix rather than illegal characters within the zip.

```
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\Media\test.zip"))
            {
                zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name=*.txt",null , @"C:\Media\", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
```

If I specify the exact file it extracts as expected:

```
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\Media\test.zip"))
            {
                zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("testfile.txt",null , @"C:\Media\", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
```

I'm using DotNetZip 1.15.0 via NuGet (https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd) on VisualStudio 2017.

Comment: On their documentation they show a space between the `name` and the `=` and the wildcard. Have you tried like this: `zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = *.txt",null , @"C:\Media\", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);`? - (https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/90a4fb68-d2f7-4f28-a7e7-9a6d15d80303.htm)

Comment: Same issue unfortunately

Comment: Same error with that change: `zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = '*.txt'", null, @"C:\Media\", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);`

Comment: Have you tried a previous version of DotNetZip?

Comment: I've gone all the way back through 23 releases, the same error occurs on all of them.

Comment: What version of .Net or .Net Core is your project targeting?

Comment: I just created a Console Application in Visual Studio 2017, added the version of `DontNetZip` you listed, and used the exact same code block as you, and got no exception. Maybe you should try re-installing the `nuget` package or look for some kind of corruption in your VS project. This code works fine for me.

Comment: I've created the project from scratch and it works fine, I cannot see any differences at all between the projects so no idea what the issues is\was. Thanks for your help Ryan.

Comment: Not sure why you had that problem. Glad you were able to get it working! :)